How to fix Kafka topic leader lost OR no leader for a kafka topic
I had to restart my 3 node kafka cluster one by one yesterday. Before restart everything was fine and there were no under replicated partitions and gradually while restarting each node - 3 topics got impacted and we have lost access to it now.
Kafka version is "3.0.0 (Commit:8cb0a5e9d3441962)"
It's a 3 server cluster
Topic has 27 partitions
3 replicas
Procedure followed for restart

Ensure only one server is restarted at a time.
First stop Kafka gracefully
Then stop Zookeeper gracefully
Reboot the server
Start Zookeeper
Start Kafka broker

I could see that 3 topics were shown as under replicated and then by reading some articles tried restarting broker and zookeeper on all servers again for it catchup again but unfortunately the moment the last broker where this topics we seen to have ISR we lost access to it and now these topcis are not having any leader.
I tried fixing it by setting "unclean.leader.election.enable" to True and then did Generate parition assignment, ran preferred replica assignment for these topics but it did not work.
Below are some screenshot from yahoo CMAK (Kafka manager)


Would really appreciate if someone please suggest how do I assign a broker to again become its leader ? and How do I get them back as ISR on all 3 servers ?
Also request to share any recommendations or care to taken going forward to avoid such issue.

Hello All, Is it possible to get this topic back to life ?
